# Wordpress 5.4 Theme Editor works on LOCAHOST but not on the LIVE theme editor site

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, https, wordpress-theming

I am having a weird situation where I can edit my theme on localhost wordpress admin using the theme editor but when I try editing on my live wordpress admin using theme editor it gives me an error "Unable to communicate back with site to check for fatal errors, so the PHP change was reverted...". I am currently using Wordpress 5.4 version and my site is already https and the owner of the theme. Anyone having the same problem? what could be the best fix for this issue? thanks

additional: I currently have no plugins installed yet. This is just a simple template for testing which works on localhost theme editor with the same version of wordpress 5.4.

I have already search and read post here on stackoverflow but unfortunately nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

it's working now on version 5.4.1, though there are times that it doesn't work. Might be a bug. I'll just have to wait for a new update.